# iconv.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, iconv

I installed libiconv from http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ make install
```

Then I add `#include <iconv.h>` declaration in my project.

I am getting following error how can I fix this?

```
fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

P.S. I am using OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, `/usr/local/include` is not in your default include path. Try adding `-I/usr/local/include` to your compilation command.

Comment: Thanks I added /usr/local/include in my LOCAL_C_INCLUDES and it works. But I am getting new error : undefined reference to 'libiconv_open'.

Comment: You also need to add `-L/usr/local/lib -liconv` in the linking command. :-)

Comment: I am using Android Ndk and I only run build_native command, to tell to truth  I dont know how to do what you said?